# Recursive class C#

Tags: c#, oop, class, recursion

Can I define constructor like this? Additional question: Can I call constructor of the class in itself constructor?

```
class SubArray
{
    List<int> array;
    string parent;
    string name;
    SubArray child;

    public SubArray(SubArray child, string name)
    {
        this.child = child;
        List<int> array = new List<int>();
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the code sample you provided you are **NOT** calling the constructor of `SubArray` from within the constructor of `SubArray`.

Comment: I know that. It was additional question

Comment: And why would you want to do that?

Comment: have you tried? what was the result? Also what are you trying to do, add new subarray objects and set their properties or replace the existing properties in one object?

Comment: The `array` variable in your constructor is a local variable

Comment: @fab because it is nicely reflecting the complex problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I know that.

Comment: In that case you can remove that line from the constructor since it serves no purpose

Comment: this must be a crude problem... or do you actually mean "creating new objects" when you say "calling the constructor" ? Anyway, a real example that explains what you are trying to achiev would be helpful

Comment: @fab i am trying to make chain of self similar objects

Comment: At the very least delegate the recursive part to a different method call.  Constructors should not perform long running operations.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no limit on that, but like any recursion - it needs a stopping condition. otherwise it will cause a stack overflow (PUN intended :)).

Comment: Extra kudos for the pun there.  :)

Answer (score 4):

I guess you could do something like this and there is no....apparent problem:

```
public SubArray(SubArray child, string name)
{
    this.child = child;
    this.array = new List<int>();
    this.name = name;

    if (child != null && child.child != null)
    {
        this.child.child = new SubArray(child.child,name);
    }
}
```