# C# - Instantiating objects of a class that contains members of its own type?

Tags: c#

I have searched everywhere for a solution to this problem but I can't find anything and this might be because I'm not phrasing it correctly so I'll elaborate as much as I can.

Basically the problem I'm having is figuring how to get the following scenario to work. Assume you have class "Employee" as such:

```
class Employee
{
    string Name { get; set; }

    Employee Manager { get; set; }

    public Employee(string name, Employee manager)
    {
        Name = name;
        Manager = manager;
    }
}
```

In your program you can then do this:

```
Employee george = new Employee("George", null);
Employee michael = new Employee("Michael", george);
```

But not this:

```
Employee michael = new Employee("Michael", george);
Employee george = new Employee("George", null);
```

Because obviously, the object "george" can't be used before it is declared.

This is problematic as for example I might be constructing my Employee objects by retrieving information from a database where I can't control the order in which the objects appear.

I can think of a few solutions but none seem "right" to me as they all come with a host of other problems.

I.e. I could technically instantiate every object with "Manager" set to null at first and once my list of Employees is populated, individually assign a manager to each employee that is supposed to have one. This feels like pointless overhead to a problem that probably has a much simpler solution.

So basically my question is, what is usually the correct practice for solving such an issue? Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursive class C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854449/recursive-class-c-sharp)

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

Comment: One solution could be you can add a new column in the table which will talk about the tree. That means the biggest boss will get `1` and then subordinate will get `2` and so on. Then the query will orderby manager first and then the subordinates.

Comment: I think you need to reconsider your design. Are you really needs instance of `Manager` in your `Employee` class. What kind of functionality `Employee` need?

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.

I'd like to point out that this is not the specific problem that I'm having, just an example of it. Maybe it's a problem that I'm supposed to fix with a different design, but I was just wondering if there are any C# / OOP solutions for issues of this type that aren't programming work-arounds, i.e. sorting the list.

Answer (score 1):

> I might be constructing my Employee objects by retrieving information from a database where I can't control the order in which the objects appear.

Every database can sort stuff. It's basic SQL. Even if you had unsorted data and no database, you could sort it in your program. So the answer will always be *sort the data, then build your objects* OR if you don't want all data made into objects, start with the one you want to get and fetch it's predecessors in a loop until you reach the first you can construct, then follow the chain you just built.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Sorting might not always be a solution to this problem because, i.e. in the example that I put forward, if two employees were the manager of each other (not possible in real life obviously but it's a possible problem in other relationships of the same type) then no type of sorting could prevent this.

I was wondering if there's a specific C# solution for this issue that isn't just a programming work-around.

Comment: @Tasos The solution to the cross-referencing is that you construct both first (maybe with `null` or using a different constructor) and later set their properties to each other.

Comment: Alright, I suppose this is what I was looking for, confirmation that this is the correct solution. Thank you very much!